# Identity Aware Proxy(IAP) for Google Cloud endpoints OpenAPI

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-iap

We have an application (say App-B) that is developed in Python 3.7 standard environment.

This application will be accessed **only** by another project (application) that is part of GAE.

Do we need to expose the App-B using Google Cloud endpoints to make this happen? If yes, according to the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine-standard) it says we need to secure App-B using IAP.
Can IAP support "application" instead of "users"? How do we go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps to Setting up Cloud IAP access:

> 1.Go to the Identity-Aware Proxy page.
>
> 2.On the right side panel, next to Access, click Add.
>
> 3.In the Add members dialog that appears, add the email addresses of groups or individuals to whom you want to grant the IAP-secured Web
> App
>
> 4.User role for the project. Members can be:
>
> a.Google Accounts: user@gmail.com
>
> b.Google Groups:
> admins@googlegroups.com
>
> c.Service accounts:
> server@example.gserviceaccount.com
>
> d.G Suite domains: example.com

Can IAP support "application" instead of "users"? Yes, IAP member can be a service account.

> A service account is a special kind of account that belongs to an
> application or a virtual machine (VM) instance, not a person.
> Applications use service accounts to make authorized API calls.

You can find detailed explanation [Enabling Cloud IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart#enabling_iap) ,[Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts).